# Issue in upgrading Spring Boot App with Apache Camel Dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

Our application is currently running on spring boot `1.5.10.RELEASE` version, and I'm trying to upgrade to spring boot `2.0.0.RELEASE` But after upgrading to `2.0.0.RELEASE` I get the following error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.app.MyApplication
```

Given Below is the build.gradle file

```
    buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    camelVersion = '2.24.0'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
}

apply from: '../common.gradle'
apply from: '../test.gradle'

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
dependencies {
           providedRuntime "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
           compile ("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.0.7")
           compile ("org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.2.RELEASE")
           compile("org.springframework:spring-jms:5.1.1.RELEASE")
           compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq:2.0.6.RELEASE")
           compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.0.4.RELEASE")
           compile("org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.2.RELEASE")
           compile("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:1.11.428")
           compile("com.amazonaws:amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib:1.0.4")
           compile ("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.0.7")
           runtime("org.apache.activemq:activemq-kahadb-store:5.15.6") 

            compile("org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot-starter:${camelVersion}")
            compile("org.apache.camel:camel-core:${camelVersion}")
            compile("org.apache.camel:camel-http-starter:${camelVersion}")
            compile("org.apache.camel:camel-http4:${camelVersion}")
            compile("org.apache.camel:camel-jsonpath:${camelVersion}")
            compile("org.apache.camel:camel-jackson:${camelVersion}")
            compile("org.apache.camel:camel-base64:${camelVersion}")
            compile("org.apache.camel:camel-groovy:${camelVersion}")
            compile("org.apache.camel:camel-jolt:${camelVersion}")
            compile("org.apache.camel:camel-jaxb:${camelVersion}")
            compile("org.apache.camel:camel-ahc:${camelVersion}")
            compile("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:3.0.3")               

 }

configurations {
              all*.exclude group: '', module: 'servlet-api'
}

springBoot {
      mainClassName = 'com.app.MyApplication'
}

war {
  archiveName = "application.war"
 }
```

I'm wondering if this is due to the camel dependencies as when I tried to use Spring Boot version `1.5.22`. It is working fine but as soon as I change this to `2.x.x` it stop working.

Comment: Well you are upgrading but you are mixing a lot of dependencies. You have Spring 5.0, 5.1 and spring boot managed dependencies. Everything should be the same. The activemq starter should not have a version and it also includes the `spring-jms` dependency. Remove the version for Spring Retry and Spring jdbc and you are using an old version of Flyway. And finally read the

Comment: I've refactored the dependency but the problem still persists. And since our project is multi-module I tried without camel dependencies and it started working. So I'm guessing this could be due to camel dependency issues

Comment: There is a `camel-spring-boot-starter` which, if not upgraded, might pul in old dependencies.

Comment: `camel-spring-boot-starter` is upgraded already. And I didn't find any old dependencies in the libs.

Comment: I tried this in Intellij and it started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got resolved when I ran this application in Intellij instead of the eclipse.